# RabbitMq Installation issue

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I am trying download and create a queque but I have problem. **This is my list what I am doing:**

1. I download erlang http://www.erlang.org/downloads (for windows x64)
2. I download rabbitmq https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html (for windows )
3. I install erlang and next install rabbimq
4. I write rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management in console and I have:

   C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins.bat  enable rabbitmq_management Plugin configuration unchanged.

   ```
   Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@----... failed.

    - Could not contact node rabbit@----.    Changes will take effect at broker restart.
    - Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
               --offline - do not try to contact broker.
   ```

   5. So i write in consol "sc query rabbitmq" and I have :

   `[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

     The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`

I know that rabbit is started by the process C:\Program Files\erl7.0\erts-7.0\bin\erlsrv.exe but I have this process so erlang was install correctly. I find people who have similar problem but they only "restart the RabbitMQ service and then try again" but I can't do this because my service does not exist.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: Does RabbitMQ show up in the services program? (This is the Services item in Administrative Tools. You can run it by searching for "Services" in the start menu.)  If it doesn't you probably haven't followed the installation procedure exactly, or you have some hyper aggressive antimalware measure in place.

Comment: In console i write serviecs.msc and I don't have RabbitMq. I did everything like this film https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9GdUOtxhhA  I have only Windows Defender

Comment: Do you have any advice??

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know. In console I am writing:

> rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
>
> rabbitmq-server start

and RabbitMQ work.